# Zebra printer GX420D doesn't use Windows settings after restart until test page is printed from Windows

Tags: java, zebra-printers, zpl

I'm using a java application to print ZPL codes directly to printer, which works just fine after I print a test page from Windows printer settings.

The problem occurs when the printer is restarted - it seems that the settings about paper size is lost, which results in the ZPL codes are printed outside the label. The problem is fixed as soon as I print as test page from Windows settings again.

How do I avoid being forced to print a test page every time the printer has been restarted.

We have label size set up in Windows printer settings but nothing else.

ZPL used:

```
^XA
^CF0,60,60
^CI28
^FO25,45
^FH
^FD[HEADER_LABEL]^FS
^FO5,115^GB590,1,2,
^FS
^CF0,40,40
^CI28
^FO30,170
^FH^FD[VISITOR_NAME]
^FS
^CF0,40,40
^CI28
^FO30,215
^FH
^FD[VISITOR_COMPANY]^FS
^CF0,35,35
^CI28
^FO30,305
^FH
^FD[HOST_NAME]^FS
^FO5,285^GB590,1,2,^FS
^CF0,30,30
^CI28
^FO30,365
^FH^FD[VALID_TO]^FS
^FO480,365
^FH^FD[CONTROL_CODE]^FS
^XZ
```

Java code used to print:

```
 public void print(String printCodes) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, PrintException {
        PrintService printService = getPrintService();
        
        
        if (printService == null)
            throw new PrintException("No print service found for printer named " + getPrinterName());
        
        byte[] bytes = printCodes.getBytes("UTF-8");
        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc doc = new javax.print.SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
        
        DocPrintJob job = printService.createPrintJob();
        job.print(doc, null);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what you mean by "ZPL codes are printed outside the label".    Do you mean they are printing onto the next label (or adjacent label)?

Comment: @MarkWarren
I sadly can't provide a picture but I can try to explain it better. The text is printed ~2cm left of the correct placement on the label, so not all text is visible on the label.

Comment: It sounds like the test print from windows adjusts the origin (using `^LH`) and your ZPL is rendering based on that non-zero origin.  Try adding a `^LHx,0` before any `^FO` / `^FT` in your label format.  Assuming an 8dpmm print head, `x` should be approx 20 * 8 = 160.

Comment: @MarkWarren I have a hard time reproducing the error on my test printer, so I also have a hard time testing if the change work. Now I have implemented your suggested change on the printer which had the issue. It's on a remote location, so I'm waiting for feedback. Thank you so far and I will leave a message if the problem is solved as soon as I know more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing using ZPL, Set the printer up as a generic text based printer. Then set the label sizes in your ZPL and/or printer. You shouldn't have to do anything with Windows test prints.